# Как сделать, чтобы flex-элемент (картинка) при адаптиве сужалась до определенного момента, а затем начинал сужаться блок с текстом?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Я использовал min-width у картинки, но страница при сужении переставёт адаптироваться, начинает масштабироваться, ломаться.
Подскажите, как это исправить?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, проблема была в ограничении у другого блока